# TFS ms.vss-work-web - notifications from "board"

Tags: .net, tfs, azure-devops, scrum

I´m currently working on an extension for Team Foundation Server 2017.

What the extension eventually should be able to do is move a work item into a specific state and then call a web service somewhere.

However I ran into a problem, it doesn't seem possible to subscribe to whenever a work item is being moved between the different swim lanes.
[image]

My current manifest file(vss-extension.json) looks like the following:

```js
 {
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "xxxx-mes-assyst-plugin",
    "version": "0.1.6",
    "name": "xxxx MES Assyst plugin",
    "description": "Connects to MES Teams assyst",
    "publisher": "xxxx-System-A-S",
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
            }
        ],
    "icons": {
        "default": "images/logo.png"
     },
    "contributions": [
    {
        "id": "sample-work-item-form-notifications",
        "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-notifications",
        "description": "Gets events about the current work item form",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "uri": "workItemNotifications.html"
        }
    }],
    "scopes": [
        "vso.work",
        "vso.work_write"  
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "workItemNotifications.html", "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "scripts", "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "images", "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "sdk/scripts", "addressable": true
        }
    ]
}
```

My workItemNotifications.html looks like the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Work item extension page sample</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="sdk/scripts/VSS.SDK.js"></script>

    <script>
        VSS.init({
            explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
            usePlatformScripts: true
        });

        VSS.ready(function () {
            // Register a listener for the work item page contribution.
            VSS.register(VSS.getContribution().id, function (context) {
                return {
                    // Called when the active work item is modified
                    onFieldChanged: function(args) {
                        console.log("onFieldChanged");
                        console.log("----------- ARGS -----------");
                        console.log(args);
                    },

                    // Called when a new work item is being loaded in the UI
                    onLoaded: function (args) {
                        console.log("onLoaded");
                        console.log("----------- ARGS -----------");
                        console.log(args);
                    },

                    // Called when the active work item is being unloaded in the UI
                    onUnloaded: function (args) {
                        console.log("onUnloaded");
                        console.log("----------- ARGS -----------");
                        console.log(args);
                    },

                    // Called after the work item has been saved
                    onSaved: function (args) {
                       console.log("onSaved");
                       console.log("----------- ARGS -----------");
                       console.log(args);
                    },

                    // Called when the work item is reset to its unmodified state (undo)
                    onReset: function (args) {
                        console.log("onReset");
                        console.log("----------- ARGS -----------");
                        console.log(args);
                    },

                    // Called when the work item has been refreshed from the server
                    onRefreshed: function (args) {
                       console.log("onRefreshed");
                       console.log("----------- ARGS -----------");
                       console.log(args);
                    }
                }
            });

            VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();    
        });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works, whenever a work item form is changed, however I want to subscribe to the event of an work item moving/changing status between the lanes.

I tried adding a target like "ms.vss-work-web.backlog-item-notifications" - Which just returned and error, because its not a valid target.

Anybody got an idea how to do that?

Comment: Why don't you just use the service hooks instead of writing an extension?

Comment: Thats a posibility, however I want to see if this can be done without any web-service in the middle. - I want to call a web-service that already exists, that I cant modify.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it cannot be achieved via VSTS Extension since there is no contribution target for the work items in board panel as far as I know. Just as Nicolai mentioned in the comments, the workaround is creating a web-service to subscribe the VSTS Service Hooks to track the change on the work items.